# Why doesn't this function exceed the value 2^31?

Tags: c++, long-integer, bit, pow, exponent

The power function (written in c++)...

```
long power (long a, long b){
    long result=1l;
    for (int i = 0;i<b;i++){
        result*=a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I do some output testing...

```
cout<<power(2l,2l)<<endl;
cout<<power(2l,4l)<<endl;
cout<<power(2l,31l)<<endl;
cout<<power(2l,32l)<<endl;
cout<<power(2l,61l)<<endl;
```

Output:

```
4
16
-2147483648
0
0
```

Well there seems to be some problem with the long falling back to a 32 bit size (instead of staying as a 64 bit). I'm wondering why this doesn't work, yet if I use the `long long` type, everything works fine.

Some extra info:

I'm using C++ and the compiler MinGW
I am running a 64-bit OS (Windows 7)

**UPDATE:**

You guys are awesome! Never thought that this type of thing would be going on.

I just checked some arbitrary PDTs using `sizeof` and this is what I found...

```
cout<<sizeof(long)<<" "<<sizeof(int)<<" "<<sizeof(char)<<" "<<sizeof(long long)<<" "<<sizeof(uint64_t)<<endl;
```

Output:

```
4 4 1 8 8
```

So, it looks like my `long` and `int` are both 32 bit in size. Some more playing around shows that the intmax_t type is also 64 bit. Practically every single PDT is capped at 64 bits, so if I ever needed to represent a 128-bit integer, does c++ have a built in class for that (something similar to `BigInteger` in Java)?

Comment: Dont guess - print the values of sizeof(long) and sizeof(int) to find out how big they are

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, I'd recommend creating a new question (or better yet, [finding a previous question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+big+integer+library)). Here's one quick link: http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the type `long` is 32 bits in your environment.

To get around similar problems, I would suggest that you use types like `uint64_t` instead of relying in the assumption that a native type has a specific size.

*EDIT*

To answer your second question (does c++ have a built in class for 128-bit integers?): No, it does not. Or rather, it does not mandate one. However, if an implementation would provide one you would be able to use something like `uint128_t`. Personally, I haven't seen any system that does this, though. There are third party libraries like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) that provide that functionality, though.

Comment: Small comment: an overflow on a signed integer is undefined behavior, so `0` is one of the possible inputs. Using an unsigned integer instead (like `unsigned long`) there would have been a wrap around and the result might not have been `0` (but `1`)

Comment: Big metal can have them. I have used several (less than 5) research machines that had int 128.

Answer (score 1):

A. trying running:

```
cout<<sizeof(long);
```

To see that it's a 32 bit.

B. I guess it is a problem with the definition of your project. even if you work on a 64 bit machine it can compile a 32 bit program so you can use it both on 32 and 64 but machines.
and long is always the size of a pointer...

C. `uint64_t` is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, as well as in C, size of `int` is architecture-dependent, and that's all true, but that catch is that 32-bit signed `int`'s go between -2^31 and (2^31-1), *not* 2^31. You are indeed overflowing a 32-bit number. You should use an `unsigned int` instead. That goes between 0 and (2^32-1).

Comment: What you say makes sense, but my ints are still 32-bit :S

Comment: Yup, what you are saying is dead on, except I would need numbers as large as 2^61, where even an unsigned int would not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Well long type takes 32 bits, so max positive value is 4294967296-1. But your function calculates value 5842587018385982521381124421=21^21.

Comment: Actually, that was 2l ^ 2l where the "l" (L in capitalized form) denotes type `long`